# How to authenticate VSTS APIs PAT using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a small service that will return items from Azure-DevOps 2019. For that I'm trying to authenticate using Personal Access Token.

Tried various ways, including converting the PAT to Base64 (with and without my username attached). For some reason, nothing seems to work.
I ended up with this:

```
var myPAT ="";
var myOrg = "";

var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("GET","https://dev.azure.com/"+ myOrg + "/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0", true);
var b = "Bearer [myPAT]";
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", b);

request.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.response));
  console.log(data);
}
request.send()
```

Whatever I've tried I could not pass the authentication.

Comment: Did you try instead of `Bearer [myPAT]` put `Basic [myPAT]`?

Answer (score 3):

So, thanks to Andre I found the issue. and it was this line that was missing (actually the ":" was the part I missed)

```
var base64PAT = btoa(":" +myPAT);
```

Comment: In that case it would be nice to upvote my answer @Yonatan if it was helpful for you and led to your actual solution ;-)

Comment: @AndreKraemer, I did. Rep is still too low for it to show :/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=azure-devops) you have use basic authorization when you want to pass your PAT in the header:

> If you wish to provide the personal access token through an HTTP
>   header, you must first convert it to a Base64 string. The resulting
>   string can then be provided as an HTTP header in the format:
>
> ```
>  Authorization: Basic BASE64PATSTRING
> ```

**Code Sample:**

```
var myPAT ="INSERT YOUR PAT HERE";
var myOrg = "INSERT YOUR ORG HERE";
var base64Pat = btoa(":"+myPAT);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("GET","https://dev.azure.com/"+ myOrg + "/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0", true);
var b = "Basic " + base64Pat;
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", b);

request.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.response));
  console.log(data);
}
request.send();
```

Make sure to insert the ":" before your pat when you convert it to base64. It won't work otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following technique when using PAT authentication from a custom Azure Dashboard widget that uses the VSS-SDK and Typescript/Javascript. The PAT generated following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) was pasted directly into "{PAT}" without the ':'.

```
import service = require("VSS/Service");
import gitWebApi = require("TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient");
import { GitHttpClient } from "TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient";
import { VssHttpClient } from "VSS/WebApi/RestClient";
import { BasicAuthTokenManager } from "VSS/Authentication/Services";

...

const gitClient: GitHttpClient = service.getClient(gitWebApi.GitHttpClient);
(gitClient as VssHttpClient).authTokenManager = new BasicAuthTokenManager("","{PAT}");

// Subsequent calls will now use PAT authentication
gitClient.getRepositories(projectId, false)
```